# Can not access an app's constant from a service

Tags: angularjs

What do i have to do in `myService.js` to access the constant 'appSettings' from app.js?

app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
        .constant('appSettings', {
            someValue: 123
        })
})();
```

Here is my services/myService.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .factory('myService', ['appSettings', MyService]);

    function MyService(appSettings) {
        console.log(appSettings.someValue)
    }
})();
```

Browser's console says `appSettings.someValue` is undefined`

Comment: use `angularobj.value`

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Where is `MyService` function defined? Is that a typo?

Comment: I fixed the code above. Missing MyService function was a typo

Comment: Have you successfully accessed the variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the problem you are facing but I can access the value.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .constant('appSettings', {
      someValue: 123
    })
})();

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('myService', ['appSettings', MyService]);

  function MyService(appSettings) {
    console.log(appSettings.someValue);
    alert(appSettings.someValue);
    
    return {
      foo: function() {}
    }
  }

  angular.module("myApp")
    .controller("sa", function($scope, myService) {
      myService.foo();
    })
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="sa"></div>
```

Comment: i had some problems with dependency injection ;)